# EqualsFilter for product active does not account for inheritance

Tags: shopware

I'm trying to fetch products from the repository which are active. However, some variants inherit the active status from their parent, meaning they have active = NULL in the `product` DB table.

The EqualsFilter will result in the following query, not fetching variants inheriting the active status:

```
SELECT `product`.`id` FROM `product` WHERE (`product`.`version_id` = :version) AND `product`.`active` = true
```

What is the proper was to filter for active products?
This is my current code:

```
$criteria = new Criteria();
$criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('active', true));
$this->productRepository->search($criteria, Context::createDefaultContext());
```

This works, but seems like a bug that one needs to go through that much work.

```
            $criteria->addFilter(
            new MultiFilter(
                MultiFilter::CONNECTION_OR,
                [
                    new EqualsFilter('active', true),
                    new MultiFilter(
                        MultiFilter::CONNECTION_AND,
                        [
                            new EqualsFilter('active', null),
                            new EqualsFilter('parent.active', true)
                        ]
                    )
                ]
            )
        );
```

Will result in this query:

```
SELECT `product`.`id` FROM `product` LEFT JOIN `product` `product.parent` ON `product`.`parent_id` = `product.parent`.`id` AND `product`.`version_id` = `product.parent`.`version_id` WHERE (`product`.`version_id` = :version) AND (`product`.`active` = true OR (`product`.`active` IS NULL AND `product.parent`.`active` = true))
```

**UPDATE**

So it seems that if one provices a SalesChannelContext and not a default Context, it works and the query equals the last one.
What is the cause of this and is there a workaround for when you don't have a sales channel context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\Shopware\Core\Framework\Context` has a `considerInheritance`-flag. This flag controls exactly the behaviour you describe.

By default this flag is set to `false`. This is due to the reason that when using the admin-api you have otherwise no way of knowing whether a specific property value comes directly from the product at hand or it's parent. This mechanism is mainly used in the administration where the parent product will be fetched always, to distinguish between inherited and not inherited properties.

When loading a product over the storefront the `considerInheritance`-flag is always that to `true`, because we do not want to additionally fetch the parent product.

If you want to change that behaviour you can use the `setConsiderInheritance()` method of the Context.
Your example code would then look like this:

```php
$criteria = new Criteria();
$criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('active', true));

$context = Context::createDefaultContext();
$context->setConsiderInheritance(true);

$this->productRepository->search($criteria, $context);
```

Keep in mind that in general you should try to not use the `createDefaultContext()`-method, refer to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/shopware/platform/issues/1245#issuecomment-673537348) for a detailed explanation.